# Where have the countries moved in Rails 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Where has the COUNTRIES constant moved to, this used to work:

```
>> ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES
NameError: uninitialized constant ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper::COUNTRIES
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
        from (irb):7
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was extracted to a separate "country_select" plugin due to some controversy over the inclusion of certain countries in the list. The current version is available on [Github](http://github.com/rails/country_select/tree/master).

Comment: From googling the culprit is Taiwan, sorry I mean "Republic of China"